# Python convert non standard characters

Tags: python, utf-8, replace, ascii, strip

I have a list that I pulled from a webpage that contains some non standard characters.

List example:

```
[<td class="td-number-nowidth"> 10Â 115 </td>, <td class="td-number-nowidth"> 4Â 635 (46%) </td>, <td class="td-number-nowidth"> 5Â 276 (52%) </td>, ...]
```

The A with the hat is supposed to be a comma.    Can someone suggest how to convert or replace these so I can get at the value 10115 as in the first value in the list?

Source code:

```
from urllib import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re, string
content = urlopen('http://www.worldoftanks.com/community/accounts/1000395103-FrankenTank').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(content)

BattleStats = soup.find_all('td', 'td-number-nowidth')
print BattleStats
```

Thanks,
Frank

Comment: your previous question suggests that you use `BeautifulSoup()` that should handle characters encoding automatically. How do you get `Â`? (provide some code)

Comment: You're right J.F.   here's the code I'm playing with (posted above).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does the website say about the encoding in it's `Content-Encoding` header? You have to get that, and decode the those strings in the list using `.decode` method. It will be like `encoded_string`.decode("encoding"). The `encoding` could be anything, `utf-8` being one of them.

Comment: then take each string and use `encoded_string.decode('utf-8')`

Comment: Unfortunately for me this answer doesn't work because the website /said/ UTF-8, but included garbage characters all the same.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the `.decode` method with the `errors='ignore'` parameter.

```
>>> s = '[ 10Â 115 , 4Â 635 (46%) , 5Â 276 (52%) , ...]'
>>> s.decode('ascii', errors='ignore')
u'[ 10 115 , 4 635 (46%) , 5 276 (52%) , ...]'
```

here is `help(''.decode)`:

```
decode(...)
    S.decode([encoding[,errors]]) -> object

    Decodes S using the codec registered for encoding. encoding defaults
    to the default encoding. errors may be given to set a different error
    handling scheme. Default is 'strict' meaning that encoding errors raise
    a UnicodeDecodeError. Other possible values are 'ignore' and 'replace'
    as well as any other name registered with codecs.register_error that is
    able to handle UnicodeDecodeErrors.
```

Comment: This worked for me, website returned garbage characters outside the claimed encoding

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an attempt?

This might work.

```
a =  ['10Â 115', '4Â 635 (46%)', '5Â 276 (52%)']
for b in a:
    b.replace("\xc3\x82 ", '')
```

Output:

```
10115
4635 (46%)
5276 (52%)
```

Depending on how constant it is (if it's always only an a with a dot), there may be better ways to go (replace anything from a \ to a space with a blank character).

Answer (score 0):

[BeautifulSoup handles character encodings automatically](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#encodings). The problem is with the printing to your console that it seems doesn't support some Unicode characters. In this case it is [`'NO-BREAK SPACE' (U+00A0)`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/A0/index.htm):

```
>>> L = soup.find_all('td', 'td-number-nowidth')
>>> L[0]
<td class="td-number-nowidth"> 10 123 </td>
>>> L[0].get_text()
u' 10\xa0123 '
```

Notice that the text is Unicode. Check whether `print u'<\u00a0>'` works in your case.

You can manipulate what output encoding is used by changing `PYTHONIOENCODING` environment variable before your run the script. Thus you can redirect the output to a file specifying `utf-8` encoding and use `ascii:backslashreplace` value for debug runs in the console without changing the script.
Example in bash:

```
$ python -c 'print u"<\u00a0>"' # use default encoding
< >
$ PYTHONIOENCODING=ascii:backslashreplace python -c 'print u"<\u00a0>"'
<\xa0>
$ PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8 python -c 'print u"<\u00a0>"' > output.txt
```

To print corresponding numbers your could split on non-breakable space to process items later:

```
>>> [td.get_text().split(u'\u00a0')
...  for td in soup.find_all('td', 'td-number-nowidth')]
[[u' 10', u'115 '], [u' 4', '635 (46%) '], [u' 5', u'276 (52%) ']]
```

Or you could replace it with a comma:

```
>>> [td.get_text().replace(u'\u00a0', ', ').encode('ascii').strip()
...  for td in soup.find_all('td', 'td-number-nowidth')]
['10, 115', '4, 635 (46%)', '5, 276 (52%)']
```